# Fs.readFile return undefined

Tags: node.js, fs

The answer to my problem is probably obvious but I can't find it.

I actually want to read a json file on a nodeJS app.

```js
var accRead = fs.readFile(__dirname + '/accounts.JSON', { endoding: 'utf8' }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err

    if (data) return JSON.parse(data)
})
```

I write this, and I don't understand why it return undefined, I have checked the Json file and there is some data.

Comment: The file content is passed to the callback, not returned.

Comment: yeah but then I set it into "accounts2" if it isn't =undefined. The callback's return should go in accRead right?

Comment: Hey @L.DZ, welcome to StackOverflow. When you call `readFile` you pass some options using an object containing `endoding`, which is a typo. I guess you meant `encoding`. If that doesn't work, try print the path of the file you're trying to read, i.e: `__dirname + '/accounts.JSON'`.

Comment: _The callback's return should go in accRead_: no, it won't, the callback is called by `readFile` at _a moment_ where `readFile` _has already returned_. If you want the result to be in `accRead`, you need to use the _synchronous_ version of the function: `fs.readFileSync`. But it's not optimal for performance, because then your code will block until the file is fully read (a problem if the file is big). You may want to read about asynchronous calls in JS. I found [this](https://medium.com/codebuddies/17e0673281ee) recently, it may be of help to you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
const accounts = () => fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/accounts.json', { endoding: 'utf8'})

const accRead = JSON.parse(accounts())

/*Logging for visualization*/
console.log(accRead)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a promise and use async/await to achieve it.

Let's suppose you have a file structure like this:

- accounts.json
- index.js

In accounts.json you have this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "test1",
        "password": "test1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "test2",
        "password": "test2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "test3",
        "password": "test3"
    }
]
```

Your index.js file should be:

```
// importing required modules
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// building the file path location
const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'accounts.json');

// creating a new function to use async / await syntax
const readFile = async () => {

    const fileContent = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return fs.readFile(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
    // printing the file content
    console.log(fileContent);
}

// calling the async function to get started with reading file etc.
readFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the follwing:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/accounts.JSON', 'utf8', function read(err, dataJSON) {
    if (err) {
       // handle err
    }
    else {
      // use/process dataJSON
    }
})
```

As already mentioned in the comments, you could use the synchronous version of the function: fs.readFileSync as well..

You could pack this also in a async function like:

```
function readJSONfile() {
   fs.readFile(__dirname + '/accounts.JSON', 'utf8', function read(err, dataJSON) {
      if (err) {
         return false
      }
      else {
         return dataJSON
      }
  })
}

async function () {
   let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       resolve(readJSONfile())
   });
   let result = await promise1; // wait till the promise resolves (*)
   if (result == false) {
     // handle err
   }
   else {
     // process/use data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of node v0.5.x you can require your `JSON` just as you would require a `JS` file.

`var someObject = require('./awesome_json.json')`

In ES6:

`import someObject from ('./awesome_json.json')`

And if you need string just use `JSON.stringify(someObject)`